# Unable to show button in material dialog

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am using material design theme in app. I am trying to show Material Design dialog in app, but in dialog positive and negative buttons are not showing. Below is my code:

```
   new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getActivity())
                    .setMessage("Do you want to close this application ?")
                    .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext,"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).show();
```

**themes.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Caketale" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/accent</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
 <!--   <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>   -->
 <!--   <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>   -->
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

 </style>

</resources>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: where do you put the  new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder()? can you show the full code?

Comment: On click of a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use it with the design library, use this style.

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Then you use it like this.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
builder.setTitle("AppCompatDialog");
builder.setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor...");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
builder.show();
```

Comment: `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.Builder()` is showing red line .

Comment: use AlertDialog

Comment: Could you please edit post without using lambda implementation.